# Is graphql's ID type necessary if I've set an unique identifier with dataIdFromObject in Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using graphql + mysql + react-apollo and here's one of the graphql type for `User` table:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

My issue with `ID scalar type` in `graphql` is that it is returned as a string when primary keys are `int` in mysql and it has created some type conflicts on the frontend with typescript.

Can I just simply not use ID scalar type at all, given that I have already set a  unique identifier with `dataIdFromObject` for each object in Apollo Client:

```
import {InMemoryCache} from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const apolloMemoryCache = new InMemoryCache(
    {
        dataIdFromObject: ({id,__typename}) => {

          return __typename+id

        }
    }
);

const client = new ApolloClient({
   link: ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink]),
   cache: apolloMemoryCache,
 });
```

Would you keep the ID type or just ditch it?

Answer (score 4):

You asked

> would you keep the ID type or just ditch it

I generally recommend keeping the ID type, and NOT exposing to the client the integer that you are using. If this is a new dataset, you're probably even going to be better off using uuids as the PK from the offset. It's going to be "safer" and "more secure", as you're less likely to accidentally give someone access to someone else's stuff.

Either way, I would recommend making the IDs "opaque", as per the Relay spec, so that you have the ability to change them later, if you change your datastore, without affecting your clients. Apps often do their own type-checking, so you want to make sure your stuff isn't going to ever change in that regard whenever possible.

Comment: I didn't consider uuids, and it may be too late to keep the primary keys from being exposed to the public. Most IDs are just for product data, forum posts etc. Nothing sensitive.

Comment: What is the security issue for PK?

Answer (score 3):

You should define a custom scalar for your resolver.

In your resolver you should add one for `ID` where you expect an int or you can do your conversion between int and string in your resolver.

```
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

const resolverMap = {
  ID: new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'ID',
    description: 'Numeric custom scalar type',
    parseValue(value) {
      let result;
      // Implement your own behavior here by setting the 'result' variable
      return result;
    },
    serialize(value) {
      let result;
      // Implement your own behavior here by setting the 'result' variable
      return result;
    },
    parseLiteral(ast) {
      switch (ast.kind) {
      // Implement your own behavior here by returning what suits your needs
      // depending on ast.kind
      }
    }
  }),
};
```

https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/blob/master/docs/source/scalars.md#custom-graphqlscalartype-instance

Answer (score 0):

try this instead
`type User {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
}`

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about this. Are there any mysql + graphql + apollo users who don't define primary keys as ID scalar type at all?